# How can I get SQL query result except one specific row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a `personnel` table. I want to get all records in this table except which has IT value as department and name is John.

These are my rows:

| Name | Department |
| --- | --- |
| John | Computer |
| John | IT |
| Kevin | Medical |
| Kevin | IT |
| Kevin | Pharmacy |

This is my query

```
select * 
from personnels per 
where (per.Name = 'John' and per.Department <> 'IT')
```

This is the result of that query:

| Name | Department |
| --- | --- |
| John | Computer |

Expected result

| Name | Department |
| --- | --- |
| John | Computer |
| Kevin | Medical |
| Kevin | IT |
| Kevin | Pharmacy |

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this;

```
SELECT * 
FROM personnels per
WHERE NOT (per.Name = 'John' AND per.Department = 'IT')
```

See [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c0bb3fd4e6908ceff48320b08a6fb0d1)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this;

```
SELECT * FROM personnels 
WHERE Name != "John" and Department != "Computer"
```